# FIX Performance Session Layer (FIXP) and SBE

Tags: c++, fix-protocol

I have a working FIX engine (C++). Now I need to access an Exchange by using SBE/FIXP. I think I can under stand SBE/FIXP concept.  However to implement those Administrative messages is a big effort. I'd like to hear some suggestions to find a best way to achieve SBE/FIXP trading like:

1. modify an existing FIX engine
2. open SBE/FIXP framework (C++ better)
3. sample SBE/FIXP demo code (C++/Java)

Answer (score 0):

For Java there is Silverflash which is a reference implementation of FIXP Session Layer.

https://github.com/FIXTradingCommunity/silverflash